# Does null conditional operator always break on first null ocurrence?

Tags: php, object, null, null-conditional-operator

Having a C# background, I always use the `?.` operator when acessing class properties (when using Entity Framework relationships).

For example, if I use this and the status class is null, it'll throw an exception since I'm trying to get a property out of a null object.

```
var order = DB.Order.Find(1);

var status = order.status.text;
```

To fix this, I could do something like this:

```
var address = order.status?.text ?? "No status";
```

The `?.` operator will break on the first null and skip the rest of the acessings.

I came across the same situation in PHP and had to do something like this:

```
$order = Orders::find(1);
$status = $order->status->text;
```

If the status is empty, it'll throw the same exception (trying to get property out of a null object).

But then I did this and it worked:

```
$status = $order->status->text ?? "No status";
```

Apparently, PHP is skipping the `->text` acessing if `status` is null.

I [created a fiddle](https://ideone.com/G8vPIQ) to check if this is not only in my environment, and surprisingly it worked just fine!

```
<?php
$j = "Hello!";
echo $a->b->c->d->e ?? $a->b->c->d ?? $a->b->c ?? $a->b ?? $j;
```

> << "Hello!"

Is this really the expected behavior of the `??` operator in PHP? Because I didnd't see this mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that the null-conditional operator (`??`) that was added in PHP 7 is basically a syntatic sugar for the [**`isset()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function as if it were used in a ternary call.

```
echo isset($a->b->c) ? $a->b->c : "Hello!";
```

The documentation for the isset function shows a clear example of an attempt to access deep array values:

```
<?php

$a = array ('test' => 1, 'hello' => NULL, 'pie' => array('a' => 'apple'));

// Checking deeper array values
var_dump(isset($a['pie']['a']));        // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a['pie']['b']));        // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a['cake']['a']['b']));  // FALSE

?>
```

The `isset()` function doesn't throw an `E_NOTICE` when the variable is null, it just skips the rest of the acessing. Since the null coalesce operator basically uses `isset()` internally, it also won't throw an exception when trying to access a property on a null object.

[Here is the link](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) to the implementation suggestion, it contains a link to the merge request containing the source code of this operator.

Comment: I could be wrong about the statement that they use isset internally, but the implementation is the same, probably.